# How to combine the mouse out functions within an if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-events

I am creating a menu and am using Javascript so when they click one of the menu options it greys out the other options and displays a sub-menu. My goal is to add an if statement within the function so that when they "mouse out" on both the sub-menu and the option that they clicked, the menu will return back to normal. Is it possible to have an if statement like so:

```
IF $("Menu2").bind('mouseout',____) AND $("Menu2Sub").bind('mouseout',____) then....
```

Comment: Can you create something on http://jsfiddle.net/ that I can see as an example? I know exactly what you need to do but I need something to start with.

Comment: No, you cannot get the browser to track event sequences for you. You'll have to have the handlers set flags and check directly somehow.

Comment: So I have tried to do it the wayjsfiddle.net/pFvtv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a function which is responsible for graying out the other options and displaying the submenu and attach it as a mouseout event to the IDs like so:

```
$("#id").mouseout(function);
```

Comment: So I have added one of the functions that complete the greying out/showing sub menus. So you are saying all I need to do now is have a mouse out on that function? Will that work because I grey out everything. I only want the mouse out to be for what I clicked and it's submenu.

Comment: It should work, as long as the function is written correctly. mouseout is a jQuery shortcut for binding an element to the mouse out event. Here, check their documentation. http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/

Comment: I tried all of these and none of them worked. I just don't think I understand how I am supposed to do this. jsfiddle.net/qqWb7/1 This kind of works but sometimes when I am hovering over the text of the link(based within the list item/picture) it reads it as if I have left the listitem. I thought this might be because I didn't have the box of the link set to the size of the picture but I do.... So for some reason I have a small area over the text and right below it that registers as mouseout. BTW I am very very new at this so any extra explanation would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag on each `Menu`. When both flags have been triggered, perform the desired function:

> the menu will return back to normal

Comment: Any tips on how to do that in dreamweaver?